# ggplot2 multiple geom_point in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I want to visualize the relationship of `y` with `A`, `B`, and `C` separately across 10 levels of a `group` variable using `geom_point()`.

My current plot can only plot `y` against `A` but I want `B` and `C` to be shown in each plot in different colors.

I was wondering how this might be achievable in `ggplot2`?

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/sng.csv')

ggplot(dat)+aes(x=A, y = y, fill = group)+geom_point()+ # How can I have `B` and `C` next to `A` with other colors
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the standard way : getting the data in long format.

```
library(ggplot2)

dat %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = A:C) %>%
  ggplot()+aes(x=value, y = y, color = name) + 
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: For distinction of points, I can think of `color`, `size`, and `shape`, is there anything else for distinguishing points from one another?

Comment: Yes, those are enough to separate the points, I think.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ggscatter` from `ggpubr`

```
library(ggpubr)
library(purrr)
ggscatter(dat, x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = "y", color = "group", palette = "jco")  %>% 
      invoke(ggarrange, ., ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

-output

[image]